# Is there a way to get JSON content tag to be the contents of a file?

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently using the Google NLP Cloud API with curl and it expects a content string in the JSON such as the below:

**In file request.json**

```
{
  'encodingType': 'UTF8',
  'document': 
  {
    'type': 'PLAIN_TEXT',
    'content': 'Enjoy your vacation!'
  }
  
}
```

From the command line I do a call such as this:

```
curl -k "https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeSentiment?key=MY-SECRET-KEY" -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @request.json
```

My question is, in a real world situation the content tag is going to be paragraphs of text.  Is there  away to do a file reference in JSON so that I don't have to build out the string programatically. i.e. something like:

```
{
  'encodingType': 'UTF8',
  'document': 
  {
    'type': 'PLAIN_TEXT',
    'content': @my_input_file_of_text.txt
  }
  
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to reference a local text file it is not possible using curl, but it is possible using `gcloud` command line. For this to work you must first [install the Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) and for reference see usage of the [gcloud ml language command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml/language).

```
gcloud ml language analyze-sentiment --content-file='/your-full-path-here/my_input_file_of_text.txt'
```

Sample run using gcloud command:
[image]

But if you cannot install the Google Cloud SDK, it is still possible to reference a file using curl. But that file should be stored in a bucket in Google Cloud Storage. For reference see [Analyzing Sentiment from Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-sentiment#analyzing_sentiment_from). Your request will look like this:

**request_gcs_file.json:**

```
{
  "document":{
    "type":"PLAIN_TEXT",
    "gcsContentUri":"gs://your-bucket-name/my_input_file_of_text.txt"
  },
  "encodingType":"UTF8"
}
```

Sample run using gcs file:
[image]